# Why does this Gremlin traversal return empty?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a Gremlin vertex with set-valued properties `emails` and `phones`. As part of my update logic, I am trying to drop and recreate these properties:

```
String key = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()
def dropped = vtx.as(key).properties('emails', 'phones').drop().<Vertex>select(key)
```

My expectation is that the vertex will get tagged by `as`, then I traverse to the properties and drop them, then use `select` to return to the vertex for further processing. However, executing this always results in an empty traversal.

I have been able to get the traversal to return a result by instead saying

```
def dropped = vtx.sideEffect(__.properties('emails', 'phones').drop())
```

but I want to ensure that the properties are dropped strictly before continuing, as I then proceed to re-insert them.

Why does the original traversal not behave as I expect it? With the `sideEffect` version, do I need to add a `barrier()` for correctness, and if so, is that sufficient?

Comment: Is it ok that `String key = ... nextInt ()` ?

Comment: @daggett It works in Groovy for assignment to String.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `drop()` is a filter step so it produces no traversers. Everything that goes into it is removed from the stream. In that way, your `select()` is never called. You can see this with with `profile()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').drop().select('a').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[])@[a]                                       808         808           1.922    19.04
DropStep                                                                                       8.138    80.60
SelectOneStep(last,a)                                                                          0.010     0.10
NoOpBarrierStep(2500)                                                                          0.026     0.26
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -          10.097        -
```

Your approach with `sideEffect()` is the correct way to do what you are trying to do. The side-effect traversal should be iterated to completion before proceeding so I would expect all properties removed when the `sideEffect()` step completes for the traverser passing through it.

Comment: Okay, I'll convert that over. It's a really surprising design choice, though, to say that _certain_ operations that reduce to empty output can be resurrected with `select` but others can't.

Comment: do you mean an "empty list" as an example of "empty output"?

Comment: Not intentionally, but it's possible I'm not being aware of the distinction between "empty list" and "no items in traversal" on certain expressions. (Is there a way to run `profile()` as  a side effect programmatically, print the output, and still return the results? The API has a signature that might mean that, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. If yes, I'll post a new question on it.)

Comment: `g.inject()` has no items in the traversal, but `g.inject().fold()` will produce an empty list, because Gremlin treats the reduction of "no traversers' to a `List` object that is empty. I thought that's the kind of meaning you had when you referred to "certain operations". If it was then I'd say that it makes more sense when you think in terms of the traversers in the stream rather than the objects that they hold. you cannot `profile()` and get a result at the same time until this is done: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2459

Comment: perhaps, said another way, a traverser that holds no object is still moving through the stream but a traverser that is "dead"/filtered away can trigger no downstream operations.

Comment: If all of the traversers are extinct, though, the Big Traversal can be resurrected with `fold()` and potentially other operations?

Comment: well, `fold()` is a reducing barrier so you do lose path history - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.9/reference/#a-note-on-barrier-steps but as long as you keep a traverser alive somehow it will continue to trigger downstream steps. i hope that answers your question - i'm not sure i understood what you meant by "Big Traversal"